# How to implement a search bar to work on same page for Cordova Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap

First of all, I'm really noob on dev and this app is not for commercial use...

I'm trying to create a "wiki app" for me, who will display all the data on same page and add a search bar to search for a string on the page, the problem is the search bar ;(

Something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp), filtering but searching inside div and working on Apache Cordova Android

This is a fraction of the code ⬇️, just imagine dozens of this with a search bar above haha

```
<div class="col-12 caixa"><!--Roupala asplenioides-->
  <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="detalhes/roupala-asplenioides.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/especies/roupala-asplenioides/capa.jpg" class="card-img-top"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4>Proteaceae</h4>
      <h6 class="card-title sp"><i>Roupala asplenioides</i> Sleumer</h6> <!-- <-- Search for this h6 string-->
      <p class="card-text">carvalho</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!--it's a bootstrap card -->
```

Can anyone help me to open a way to do that? :)

Thanks!! and sorry for my bad english...